# How to provide files depending upon folder path which can be inserted dynamically

Tags: node.js, fileserver

I'm creating a app, I want to get the folder path from the user which contains an html report which has some internal links to files in that folder, I want to create a node.js application which provides link to the primary htm file and then on clicking the internal links provides the other htm files, I know I can use a file server but there are going to be multiple paths not just one path so the file server cant be started in multiple folders

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Can I start file server in multiple folders ??

Comment: you can read up the html file and serve it as a response too! this is what file server does essentially

Comment: Yes, But the main html file has internal links to other files

Comment: no problem. you can define a wildcard route with express and catch other links in the html file. or you can do use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser to take out all the external links out of the requested html file too.

Comment: How can I add a wild card route if the internal links point to a file in a folder with the same file